Manage generated folders by build_runner while CI/CD automation
I am trying to build release apk with Github CI/CD automation. I have Used Jsonserializable and Intl packages in my project. And build_runner is generating generated folders in project which we doesn't push to github as these are for development only. Just because i am using reference of that folder in my project when i add build release command to yml file, github is throwing errors for that references. How can i manage this folder ??
Should i upload/push these folder to github or what is correct way.
below are the import and error i get while github build release.

lib/app/app.dart:13:8: Error: Error when reading
'lib/generated/l10n.dart': No such file or directory
lib/models/model.dart:9:6: Error: Error when reading
'lib/network/models/model.g.dart': No such file or directory part
'model.g.dart';

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks

You can have a step before the build that generates all for the CI, and so you will also test that the code could generate on CI, something like:
Check the last 3 commands of this yaml for github actions:
on:
  pull_request:
      branches:
      - main

name: Build apk

jobs:
  run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          channel: 'stable'
      - name: Setup JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: 11
          distribution: 'corretto'
      - name: Setup Android SDK
        uses: android-actions/setup-android@v2

      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: dart run build_runner build
      - run: flutter build apk

